# Can Test 3rd Party Flash web pages using Selenium?

Tags: flash, selenium, selenium-rc

I need to test 3rd party flash page which I used for my web site using Selenium or Selenium RC.
I read one tutorial, It said "To test Flash Objects it is necessary to know the "internals" of the flash object and you must have the ability to add some code to the flash object. You cannot test any flash you find in the net, it must be yours!"
Is it true? Can I test 3rd party flash pages with Selenium RC or Selenium ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common question and I will refer you to the selenium groups page where they say the same thing you mentioned in your question; Selenium cannot be used to test flash

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/selenium-users/flash/selenium-users/urx3CY3lPRY/WIA-sblzTu8J